# Scheduled reminder not sending to manual recipients

Tags: scheduled-reminders

The message is sending when I test with a sign up but I have included a manual recipient of the organization email of info@emptyhometax.org so I receive notice when there is a sign up or contributions. That isn't working. Any trouble shooting tips? I do not want to manage these notifications through the contribution page I want this to go through a scheduled reminder. The cron seems to be working fine and the scheduled reminder executes I just am not receiving[image] an email at the manual recipient address.

Answer (score 3):

Its a known issue reported at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2475

Had to use [scheduledccrecipients](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/scheduledccrecipients) extension as an alternate.